# Drawbacks of not returning 0 when overriding 'compare()' in Java 1.5 and Java 1.7

Tags: compare, java, comparator, comparable

This is the comparator I wrote to to sort Nodes based on cost.

```
public class MyCostComparator implements Comparator<Node>{
    public int compare(Node a, Node b){
        if(a.pathCost > b.pathCost)
            return 1;
        else
            return -1;
    }
}
```

I find that it's behaviour is different on my machine (Java 1.7) and on the Uni's server (Java 1.5). However when I make it:

`if(a.pathCost >= b.pathCost)` , it seems to work fine on 1.5, but the other way on 1.7.

Also, what's the drawback of NOT returning zero when the values are equal?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The "drawback" is that `TreeSet`, `TreeMap`, and basically all comparison-based data structures won't work at all.  Not even a little bit.  In particular, `TreeSet.contains` will *always* return `false`, and `TreeMap.get` will *always* return null.

Comment: Yup.  `TreeSet.contains(x)` will return true if and only if there's an element `y` in the set such that `comparator.compare(x, y) == 0`.

Answer (score 5):

If you never return zero, then an object will appear not equal to itself. This violates the contract of `Comparable` and prevents any collection that relies on it from working properly (or at all).

Java 7 has also introduced a new kind of sorting algorithm for `Collections.sort` and will throw an `IllegalArgumentException` if it detects that the `Comparable` contract is violated. This is a change to earlier versions, which silently ignored the fact.