# Sorting an array according to its Geolocation positions

Tags: java, android, eclipse, sorting, android-studio

I have an array with lat and lng in the custom model . i want to sort the array so that minimum distance from my location comes at the top position and so on.

Here is what i have tried

```
               myLocation = new Location("");

                myLocation.setLatitude(Double.valueOf(MyApplication.getInstance().getLatitude()));
                myLocation.setLongitude(Double.valueOf(MyApplication.getInstance().getLongitude()));
                Collections.sort(pings, new DistanceComparator());


private class DistanceComparator implements java.util.Comparator<PingModel>
    {
        @Override
        public int compare(PingModel lhs, PingModel rhs)
        {
            Location lhsLocation = new Location("");

            lhsLocation.setLatitude(Double.valueOf(lhs.latloc));
            lhsLocation.setLongitude(Double.valueOf(lhs.lngloc));

            Location rhsLocation = new Location("");

            rhsLocation.setLatitude(Double.valueOf(lhs.latloc));
            rhsLocation.setLongitude(Double.valueOf(lhs.lngloc));

            return (int)rhsLocation.distanceTo(myLocation) - (int)lhsLocation.distanceTo(myLocation);
        }
    }
```

The result is not sure what kind of sorting it is doing but its not according to distance.

Comment: can you put what is 'pings' and distanceTo()

Comment: Pings is an array of custom models, and distanceTo is a regular Google Location function that calculates distance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a copy-paste error. Change these 2 lines:

```
rhsLocation.setLatitude(Double.valueOf(lhs.latloc));
rhsLocation.setLongitude(Double.valueOf(lhs.lngloc));
```

to:

```
rhsLocation.setLatitude(Double.valueOf(rhs.latloc));  // It's rhs!
rhsLocation.setLongitude(Double.valueOf(rhs.lngloc)); // It's rhs!
```

Apart from this, you shouldn't convert to `int` before subtracting the distances. In fact, you should avoid using subtraction as the return value of a comparator. This has some well-known flaws, in particular, as distances are `float` values, they might not fit into an `int`. And what is more important, the result of the subtraction might not fit into an `int`. This means that the `int` you'd be returning might overflow, leading to unexpected results.

I'd recommend you to use clear, understandable code, instead of smart*ish*, tricky code. Consider changing the last line of your comparator to a common tri-state if:

```
float lhsDistance = lhsLocation.distanceTo(myLocation);
float rhsDistance = rhsLocation.distanceTo(myLocation);

if (lhsDistance < rhsDistance) {
    return -1;
} else if (lhsDistance > rhsDistance) {
    return 1;
} else {
    return 0;
}
```

Note: if the values you're comparing are in fact equal, then you must return 0 in your comparator. Otherwise, you might experience subtle, nasty bugs, as explained in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14903104/drawbacks-of-not-returning-0-when-overriding-compare-in-java-1-5-and-java-1).

Comment: tried this result still weir,d and not sorted correctly

Comment: @MuhammadUmar Please provide a sample list of pings and the value of `myLocation`, so we can further help.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this will help, but I was working on a similar project and found this link to be very helpful : http://www.geodatasource.com/developers/java .

Basically if you have you location; use the distance function to calculate new position - your position, and then sort based on this.  Loop through the array of locations, and sort based on results.

Hope it helps.

Dan.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try following

```
return Float.compare(lhsLocation.distanceTo(myLocation), rhsLocation.distanceTo(myLocation))
```

Answer (score 0):

Converting to int before substraction might not always work. For example, if your `distanceTo()` function return km and the distance from your point and the data points is within 1 km then the result of subtraction may be 0.

Instead of

```
return (int)rhsLocation.distanceTo(myLocation) - (int)lhsLocation.distanceTo(myLocation);
```

Try

```
return (rhsLocation.distanceTo(myLocation) - lhsLocation.distanceTo(myLocation)) > 0 ? 1 : -1;
```